# Can I reduce queries while iterating a RelatedManager object within a template?

Tags: django

This is a hypothetical for simplicity. In my Django app I have models for Kit, KitSku, and Sku. The KitSku model associates a Sku with a Kit and also provides the quantity of that Sku in that kit. In the template I have something like:

```
<!-- SELECT * FROM kitsku_table WHERE kit_id = <Kit.id> -->
{% for kitsku in kit.kitsku_set.all %}
  <!-- SELECT * FROM sku_table WHERE sku = <KitSku.sku> -->
  <div>{{ kitsku.sku.name }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Now, the problem here is that Django is querying all of the KitSku rows and *then* it queries each sku within that for loop in a separate SQL query for each iteration.

Can I make the SQL query resulting from the kitsku_set.all() call perform a JOIN with the Sku model?

That first query needs to be more like:

```
SELECT * FROM kitsku_table k LEFT JOIN sku_table s ON (k.sku = s.sku) 
WHERE k.kit_id = <Kit.id>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this type of logic in the view, and use [select_related()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) to directly query the foreign keys

```
kitskus = Kit.objects.get(id=3).kitsku_set.select_related('sku')
return direct_to_template(request, "mytemplate.html", {'kitskus': kitskus})
```

Comment: Fair enough. Using select_related() in my view is doing the trick. I just though maybe there was some Django magic in there.

Answer (score 1):

Im just copying an answer for a similar question, but i think this is a much better approach.

view

```
newsletters = Newsletter.objects.prefetch_related('article_set').all()\
                    .order_by('-year', '-number')

return render_to_response('newsletter/newsletter_list.html',
                          {'newsletter_list': newsletters})
```

template

```
{% block content %}
  {% for newsletter in newsletter_list %}
    <h2>{{ newsletter.label }}</h2>
    <p>Volume {{ newsletter.volume }}, Number {{ newsletter.number }}</p>
    <p>{{ newsletter.article }}</p>
    <ul>
    {% for a in newsletter.article_set.all %}
      <li>{{ a.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Here is the complete explanation:
Hopes it helps

[Iterating over related objects in Django: loop over query set or use one-liner select_related (or prefetch_related)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014704/iterating-over-related-objects-in-django-loop-over-query-set-or-use-one-liner-s)