# Iterating over related objects in Django: loop over query set or use one-liner select_related (or prefetch_related)

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a newsletter application where a newsletter has multiple articles within each issue. I want to display a summary page online that lists the newsletter year, volume and label, and then in an unordered list display all the articles in the issue. I am quite new to Django so I am trying to determine the best way to do this.

I have the models defined (just the relevant parts):

**`Models.py`:**

```python
class Newsletter(models.Model):
    volume = models.ForeignKey(Volume)
    year   = models.IntegerField()
    season = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=VOLUME_SEASON)
    label  = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    number = models.IntegerField()

class Article(models.Model):
    newsletter = models.ForeignKey(Newsletter)
    section    = models.ForeignKey(Section)
    title      = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

What I want to see on the web looks like:

```
<h2>Spring 2012</h2>
<p>Volume 14, Number 1</p>
<ul>
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
    <li>Baz</li>
</ul>

<h2>Winter 2011</h2>
<p>Volume 13, Number 4</p>
<ul>
  <li>Boffo</li>
</ul>
```

Pretty simple. However, I am confused by the best way to write my view. Whether to use:

- Two lists which I `zip()` and then iterate over in the template
- Use the `select_related()` queryset
- Use the `prefetch_related()` queryset

I have it working using the first option:

**`Views.py`:**

```python
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from www.apps.newsletter.models import Newsletter, Article

def index(request):
    article_group = []
    newsletter = Newsletter.objects.all().order_by('-year', '-number')
    for n in newsletter:
        article_group.append(n.article_set.all())
    articles_per_newsletter = zip(newsletter, article_group)

    return render_to_response('newsletter/newsletter_list.html',
                              {'newsletter_list': articles_per_newsletter})
```

And then render it using the following template:

**`Newsletter_list.html`:**

```html
{% block content %}
  {% for newsletter, articles in newsletter_list %}
    <h2>{{ newsletter.label }}</h2>
    <p>Volume {{ newsletter.volume }}, Number {{ newsletter.number }}</p>
    <p>{{ newsletter.article }}</p>
    <ul>
    {% for a in articles %}
      <li>{{ a.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Pretty straightforward, but as I am pretty new to Django I was wondering if what I am doing is completely inefficient in terms of its powerful ORM. I would love to not have to make a list on-the-fly and then `zip()` the two lists together if there is a faster way.

TIA.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The approach you are doing now will be **heavily** inefficient, because it will result in an 1+N number of queries. That is, 1 for the query of all your Newsletters, and then 1 for every single time you evaluate those `n.article_set.all()` results. So if you have 100 Newletter objects in that first query, you will be doing 101 queries.

This is an excellent reason to use `prefetch_related`. It will only result in 2 queries. One to get the Newsletters, and 1 to batch get the related Articles. Though you are still perfectly able to keep doing the `zip` to organize them, they will already be cached, so really you can just pass the query directly to the template and loop on that. :

**view**

```
newsletters = Newsletter.objects.prefetch_related('article_set').all()\
                    .order_by('-year', '-number')

return render_to_response('newsletter/newsletter_list.html',
                          {'newsletter_list': newsletters})
```

**template**

```
{% block content %}
  {% for newsletter in newsletter_list %}
    <h2>{{ newsletter.label }}</h2>
    <p>Volume {{ newsletter.volume }}, Number {{ newsletter.number }}</p>
    <p>{{ newsletter.article }}</p>
    <ul>
    {% for a in newsletter.article_set.all %}
      <li>{{ a.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Great! I thought I was going about it in an inefficient way. I just tried your code sample, and unfortunately the **for** loop on newsletter.article_set.all doesn't return anything?

    {% for a in newsletter.articles_set.all %}
Any idea what I have done wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You wrote `articles_set.all` when it should be `article_set.all` @tatlar. See [following relationships backward](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) for more information.

Comment: Ahem. Apologies. Thanks much to both of you!

Comment: @jdi Is there similar solution if I want latest 5 articles for each newsletter?

Comment: @Acute - Use the [**slice**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#slice) template tag {% for a in newsletter.article_set.all|slice:"5" %} will get the first five results. You will need to make sure you have sorted the queryset with an **order_by** in the view.