# Display multiple models in one view in Django

Tags: python, django

i'm a beginner in Django and i have a problem ….
I created an application(name :PQR) with 3 models (Patient / Question / Reply)
I want to see a views with the name of the patient at the top, under this, all questions availables and if applicable, the answers next to the question (some patient may have empty reply / no reply).
I know how to display the answers for a patient but I would like to display EVERY questions and if available, I want to provide the reply but I don't know how to write this in my view?

This is my model :

```
Class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

def listReply(self):
    replies = Reply.objects.filter(patient= self.id)
    return replies

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.question_text


class Reply(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient)
    reply_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.reply_text)
```

This is my view :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.template import RequestContext
from .models import Patient, Question, Reply

def list(request):
    list_patient = Patient.objects.order_by('name') context = RequestContext(request, {'list_patient':list_patient,'welcome': 'Welcome on my page Django !',
})
return render(request, 'PQR/list.html', context)

def detail(request, patient_id):
    patient = get_object_or_404(Patient, pk=patient_id)
    list_question = Question.objects.all()
    Replies4MyPatient = Reply.objects.filter(patient=patient_id)
    return render(request, 'PQR/detail.html', locals())
```

And this is my urls :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.list, name ='list_patient'),
    url(r'^(?P<patient_id>[0-9]+)/patient/$', views.detail, name ='detail_patient'),
```

And this is my template :

```
{% load staticfiles %} 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'Forum/style.css' %}" /> 
<div> 
<h1>Patient details : {{ patient }}</h1>    
</div> 
<fieldset> 
{% csrf_token %} 
{% for reply in Replies4MyPatient %} 
        </br><abcd>{{ reply.question }}</abcd></br> 
        </br> 
            <li>{{ reply }}</li> 
{% endfor %} 
</fieldset></br> 
<a href="{% url 'list_patient' %}"/> <input type="button" value="Look Back"/>
```

Thanks you for your help !

Comment: And what is your question?!?

Comment: what is `pk` in this statement `pk=patient_id` ??

Comment: You need 1) to clarify the question and change the title 2) to add a context to `return render(request, 'PQR/detail.html', locals())` to tell him to use `list_question` and `patient`,  and 3) to use `list_question` and `patient` in `'PQR/detail.html'`. If you have issues with this template, add it to your question

Comment: i have found a kind of solution here : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014704/iterating-over-related-objects-in-django-loop-over-query-set-or-use-one-liner-s]

Answer (score 4):

The function `render` builds the html to return with a template and a context. In your template `PQR/detail.html`, you use `{{ patient }}` and `Replies4MyPatient`. You need to build a context with these values and to pass it to `render`

```
def detail(request, patient_id):
    patient = get_object_or_404(Patient, pk=patient_id)
    list_question = Question.objects.all()
    Replies4MyPatient = Reply.objects.filter(patient=patient_id)
    context = {'patient' : patient, 'Replies4MyPatient' : Replies4MyPatient}
    return render(request, 'PQR/detail.html', context=context)
```