# Django: Not able to access prefetch_related values in template

Tags: python, django

**UPDATE**

I changed my query to this:

```
ClinicDoctorDayShift.objects.filter(clinic_doctor__doctor_id = doctor_id)
```

With this I am able to get all the values. But as you can see, I am not using `prefectch` now. Is this inefficient if I have to get many doctors like `filter` by name?

Template has this now:

```
{% for vis in visitinghours %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                {{ vis.clinic_doctor.doctor.full_name }}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{ vis.clinic_doctor.clinic.name }}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{ vis.day_shift.day.day }}

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{ vis.day_shift.time }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
```

**ORIGINAL**

First website. Firs time using Django.
I am using this Query right now in view:

```
visitingQuerySet = ClinicDoctor.objects.filter(doctor_id = doctor_id).prefetch_related('clinicDoctor_dayShift').all()
```

Then in template I want to have something like this:

```
{% for vis in visitinghours %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            {{ vis.doctor.full_name }}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            {{ vis.clinic.name }}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            {{ vis.clinicdoctordayshift.id }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>


I can get first two `<td>` but not others if I try to get values from other models.
```

My models are:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
   full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   clinics = models.ManyToManyField(Clinic, through='ClinicDoctor', related_name='doctors')

class ClinicDoctor(models.Model):
   doctor = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='doctorsF') 
   clinic = models.ForeignKey(Clinic, related_name='clinicsF')

class Day(models.Model):
   day = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Shift(models.Model):
   shift = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   days = models.ManyToManyField(Day, through='DayShift', related_name='day_shift')


class DayShift(models.Model):
   time = models.TimeField()
   day = models.ForeignKey(Day, related_name='to_day')
   shift = models.ForeignKey(Shift, related_name='to_shift')
   clinics_doctors = models.ManyToManyField(ClinicDoctor, through='ClinicDoctorDayShift', related_name='clinicDoctor_dayShift')

class ClinicDoctorDayShift(models.Model):
   clinic_doctor = models.ForeignKey(ClinicDoctor, related_name='to_clinicDoctor')
   day_shift = models.ForeignKey(DayShift, related_name='to_dayShift')
```

I want to be able to be able to get `Day.day`, `Shift.shift` and `DayShift.time` as well.

Is my `prefetch_related` wrong? 
Is it Ok to have this in view after that `prefetch_related`:

```
if visitingQuerySet:
```

I mean will this cause any extra `DB` hits or this will be the first point where it will be actually evaluated?

Currently I can see these two queries being executed for that part:

```
SELECT 
    health_clinicdoctor.id, 
    health_clinicdoctor.doctor_id, 
    health_clinicdoctor.clinic_id, 
    health_clinicdoctor.is_active 
FROM health_clinicdoctor 
WHERE health_clinicdoctor.doctor_id = 14

SELECT 
    (health_clinicdoctordayshift.clinic_doctor_id) AS _prefetch_related_val_clinic_doctor_id, 
    health_dayshift.id, 
    health_dayshift.time, 
    health_dayshift.day_id, 
    health_dayshift.shift_id
 FROM health_dayshift 
 INNER JOIN health_clinicdoctordayshift 
    ON ( health_dayshift.id = health_clinicdoctordayshift.day_shift_id ) 
 WHERE health_clinicdoctordayshift.clinic_doctor_id IN  (1, 2, 3)
```

Kindly help.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014704/iterating-over-related-objects-in-django-loop-over-query-set-or-use-one-liner-s

Comment: Not duplicate. I have more than two models involved. Which are confusing to be. If I had only two models involved I would have found solution on SO/Google.

Comment: The link I provided is absolutely relevant. Also of note: you are prefetching on `clinicDoctor_dayShift` yet you call it like `clinicdoctordayshift`. Shouldn't your template code be calling: `clinicDoctor_dayShift`?

Comment: I have tried many ways which didn't work. This is just one I left there. 

Also, I changed the query please have a look at it. I am able to reach the values that I need. But I am not sure if it is efficient as it is not using any `prefetch`

Please see the update